# Adding Feeds to Feedjira via Front-End

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rss, feedjira

I'm looking to add feeds via the front-end to be fetched by Feedjira, I've followed the basic Railscast tutorial and got 1 feed set up and working. What I can't wrap my head around is allowing me to add a feed to feedjira via the front end (e.g. text box) and then letting the cron job pick it up and parse it.

I have a user model and posts model, with a default Feedjira set-up. I'm guessing I need a 'feeds' table in the user model which stores the URL's of the users desired RSS feeds and then passes them into Feedjira to be parsed?

Pretty new at rails/ruby and would love some help/guidance on this matter.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Once you have URL store in a table, or in a field of your User model, you can parse it in your rake task.

In your task, itinerates users, or feeds, and do that you did with one feed inside your loop.

So finally, let your cron job do the job for your at interval time.